# Can I cache a cfldap query?

Tags: caching, coldfusion, ldap

If I cannot, is there a scope that will make the same `cfldap` query available to all users? I'm just trying to cut down on the number of times it is called, since it's a cross-server call.

Comment: You could add the query into `application` scope after it's returned.

Comment: Should I just use isDefined() to check whether or not it should fetch the ldap data?

Comment: Google the difference between `isDefined()` and `structkeyExists()`

Comment: You need to give this more thought.  ldap data changes as people come and go.

Comment: @DanBracuk This is why i had hoped to cache it for a day or so.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Oddly, none of this seems to work. If I use `<cfset Application.phonebook = ldapQueryResults > ` then reload the page, the variable gets lost.

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question and include in the question the code that does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - write some code that gets your ldap data and persists it somewhere.  This could be a database, text file, or perhaps even a ColdFusion variable in the server scope.

Step 2 - Schedule that code to run at whatever frequency is good enough for your requirements.

The reason I mentioned server scope instead of application is that I'm not sure how hard it is to write application variables using scheduled jobs.  I've never had a reason to try.